# gridArrange in Shiny - manipulating individual plot size

Tags: r, shiny, grid

I struggle to increase the size of plots when using `gridArrange` in Shiny. I included an example of the problem. I would like the plots to fill the available space, which is much larger. When I enlarge the browser window to full screen, the gaps between the plots increase, but the size of the plots does not change. I tried to add `widths` and `heights` parameters, but then I keep getting the error: `only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"`. Also, this is working fine when not run in the reactive context.

Here is the fragment of my code used to render the plot:

```
observeEvent(input$enter_symb,{
    req(length(input$enter_symb) > 0)
    lista_g <- list()
    output$bar_out <- renderPlot({
    for (i in unique(input$enter_symb)){
                            a <- GLAST_RT_TPM_app[Symbol %in% i]
                            a$ENSEMBL <- NULL 
                            a <- melt(a, id.vars = colnames(a)[1])
                            a$IP_or_S1 <- ""
                            a$IP_or_S1[a$variable %like% "S1"] <- "Total Tissue"
                            a$IP_or_S1[a$variable %like% "IP"] <- "Ribo-Tag IP"
                            a$region <- ""
                            a$region[a$variable %like% "cerebellum"] <- "Cerebellum"
                            a$region[a$variable %like% "cerebrum"] <- "Cerebrum"
                            tutul <- unique(a$Symbol)
                            lista_g[[i]] <- a
                             }
                            ploty <- lapply(lista_g, plot_universal)
                            do.call(grid.arrange, c(ploty, ncol=3))


    })
})
```

[Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPpbu.png)

I struggled for hours, so any hints welcome:)

**Update: Here is the whole code:**

#### UI

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(tagList(
  fluidPage(
    title = "test",
    absolutePanel(
      bottom = 400,
      right = 30,
      width = 380,
      draggable = TRUE,
      wellPanel(
        actionButton("go", "Go!")

  ),
  # end of well panel
  style = "opacity: 0.70"
),
# end of absolute panel
    imageOutput(outputId = "bar_out")

  )
))
```

#### Server

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

data <- data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:30,6,rep=TRUE)))

plot_universal <- function(x){
  g <- ggplot(data=x, aes(y=value, x=variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge(width = 0.3), width = 0.6) +
    scale_fill_manual(guide = FALSE, values=alpha(c('#e89900',"#69ff65",'#e89900' , "#69ff65"), 0.8))+
    # geom_text(aes(label = round(value, digits = 0)), vjust = -1, size = 4) +
    labs(y = '', 
         x = '') +
    # scale_colour_manual(name = NULL, values = c("black", "black"), labels = c('c2','c1'))+
    # guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 15, size = 10))) +
    theme(title = element_text(size = 16, face = "plain"),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 22),
          text = element_text(size = 12),
          axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, face = "plain"),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 18, face = "plain"),
          legend.title.align = 0.5,
          strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20, face = "plain"),
          legend.position = "top",
          legend.direction = "horizontal",
          aspect.ratio = 1.5) +
    ggtitle(unique(x[[1]]))
  return(g)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  choose_rows <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)  

  observeEvent(input$go,{
    lista_g <- list()
    output$bar_out <- renderPlot({
      for (i in unique(choose_rows)){
        a <- data[choose_rows,]
        a$ENSEMBL <- NULL 
        a <- melt(a, id.vars = colnames(a)[1])
        lista_g[[i]] <- a
      }

      ploty <- lapply(lista_g, plot_universal)
      do.call(grid.arrange, c(ploty, ncol=3, nrow=2))

    })
  })   

  session$onSessionEnded(function(){
    stopApp()
  })
}
```

Comment: please send the ui code. I think we should do it in ui part

Comment: Thanks, and sorry it took so long. I updated the original question with a my code, reduced to minimal example.